# Temporal Foreign Key in Sql Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys

Which is the best practice to link tables which have unique relation for a determined period of time?

**Example 1**

Tab_Civil_Status:

| ID | NAME | ID_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jenny | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | 2 |

Tab_Civil_Status_Desc:

| ID_STATUS | STATUS_DESC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Single |
| 2 | Married |

Tab_Civil_Events:

| PERSON-ID | EVENT | REF_Date | new-Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Wedding | 10/5/2017 | 2 |

A query to `Tab_Civil_Status` should provide the below:

Case A:

```sql
Select * FROM `Tab_Civil_Status` […] Where REF_Date = 1/1/2020
```

| ID | NAME | ID_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jenny | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | 2 |

Case B:

```sql
Select * FROM `Tab_Civil_Status` […] Where REF_Date = 1/1/2016
```

| ID | NAME | ID_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jenny | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | 1 |

**Example 2**

Tab_Orders:

| ID | Order_Code | Product_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 |

Tab_Products:

| Product_Id | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Meta |

Tab_Products_Events:

| Product_Id | EVENT | REF_Date | Old_Name | New_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Change_Name | 1/12/2020 | Facebook | Meta |

These are simplified sample, what I am looking for is the best practice to structure tables and queries for similar cases; the logic to apply rather than the actual code to use.

**a -** Is the best practice to have an "Event Table" as in the above cases tracking the changes? or there are better ways?

I know there might be sevaral ways to reach the same scope, another sample is the below

`Tab_Products_Events_Sample_2`:

| Product_Id | EVENT | REF_Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Given _Name | 1/12/2010 | Facebook |
| 2 | Change_Name | 1/12/2019 | Meta |

**b -** is there a more efficient query than the below? Also based on the above point

```sql
@Selected_date = '1/1/2019'

SELECT 
    o.[Order_Code], 
    ifnull(e.[Old_Name],p.[Product_Name]) as p_name
FROM Tab_Orders as o
LEFT JOIN Tab_Products as p
ON o.[Product_Id]  = p.[Product_Id]
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT top 1 t.[Old_Name] 
   FROM Tab_Products_Events as t
   WHERE o.[Product_Id]  = t.[Product_Id]
        and t.[REF_Date] >= @Selected_date
   ORDER BY t.[REF_Date] desc
) e
```

result

| Order_Code | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| a | Apple |
| b | Facebook |

Thanks

Comment: Not enough Info:  What happens if Person-ID Event is 2 Divorced with a date of 2018 exists?   I think what you're wanting to do is cross apply to your event table top 1 where the Ref_Date > = your refDate from where clause and PseroNID = PersonID order by the ref Date Asc  but then you are flipping the status based on divorced, single etc... and your event table only has a year value when multiple things could happen in a year... so .... structure doens't support what you're attempting to do IMO.

Comment: Hi, thanks to let me note that, actally the date should including the day.. I am editing

Comment: Please post a script containing DDL for your tables (hopefully with descriptive table names) and insert statements for your sample data. It seems to me that your schema is flawed since we typically expect a M:M relationship between event and attendee; that requires an intersection table. It's not clear if you are asking a schema design question or a tsql query question (or perhaps both).

Comment: A temporal table with PersonID, StatusID would work imo. Then you could run queries like "what was Person 1's status as of 2016-01-01?"

Comment: @Smor I added further information to the question; actually my question is about either the model/schema of the table and at the same time which would be the most efficient way to query the tables. as I suppose the way the tables are created might simplify/complexify the following queries. So I can adopt the schema to the most efficient query. I've added some more samples, I am looking more to the correct logical approach then a working solution.

Comment: There're already 2 votes to close so it's pointless to answer.  Imo @BenThul is correct and you could save yourself a lot of grief by using System Version'ed temporal table(s)

Comment: @SteveC  I was not aware of this type of tables or how they worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: my answer is based on the first example

**1st approach**: generating date ranges

You should first extract the date ranges for each person status using a similar query:

```sql
SELECT 
    PERSON_ID, new_Status, REF_Date, 
    ISNULL(LEAD(REF_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY REF_DATE), GETDATE()) End_DATE
FROM
    Tab_Civil_Events
```

As an example, consider the following sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tab_Civil_Events
(
    PERSON_ID INT,  
    EVENT VARCHAR(50),  
    REF_Date DATETIME,  
    new_Status INT
)

INSERT INTO Tab_Civil_Events(PERSON_ID, EVENT, REF_Date, new_Status)
VALUES (2, 'Wedding', '10/5/2017', 2),
       (2, 'Divorce', '10/5/2018', 1),
       (2, 'Wedding', '10/5/2019', 2),
       (2, 'Divorce', '10/5/2020', 1)

SELECT 
    PERSON_ID, new_Status, REF_Date, 
    ISNULL(LEAD(REF_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY REF_DATE), 
    GETDATE()) End_DATE
FROM
    Tab_Civil_Events
```

This will result in the following table:

| PERSON_ID | new_Status | REF_Date | End_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2018-10-05T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | 1 | 2018-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2019-10-05T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | 2 | 2019-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2020-10-05T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2022-01-29T09:47:52.7Z |

- [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3c64/3/0)

The second step is to create a common table expression to query the data. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @QueryDate DATETIME  = '20190501'

;WITH CTE_1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PERSON_ID, 
        new_Status, 
        REF_Date, 
        ISNULL(LEAD(REF_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY REF_DATE), 
        GETDATE()) End_DATE
    FROM 
        Tab_Civil_Events
)
SELECT 
    CTE_1.PERSON_ID, 
    dsc.STATUS 
FROM
    CTE_1 
INNER JOIN 
    Tab_Civil_Status_Desc dsc ON CTE_1.new_Status = dsc.ID 
WHERE 
    @QueryDate BETWEEN REF_Date AND End_DATE
```

Using the sample data I provided previously, this query will give the following result:

| PERSON_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Single |

- [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d290cf/1/0)

While changing the date value to `20191101`

```sql
SET @QueryDate = '20191101'
```

Will result in the following values:

| PERSON_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Married |

Make sure that you have created the appropriate indexes to support your queries.

For example:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED  INDEX IX_PersonId_RefDate 
ON Tab_Civil_Events(PERSON_ID, REF_DATE) 
INCLUDE(new_status);
```

**2nd approach**: retrieving the nearest event date

You should first retrieve the maximum event dates for each person having a value smallest than the given date:

```sql
SELECT 
    PERSON_ID,
    MAX(Ref_Date) AS event_date 
FROM 
    Tab_Civil_Events
WHERE 
    Ref_Date <= @QueryDate
GROUP BY 
    PERSON_ID
```

Next, you should join this query with the events table to get the status information as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @QueryDate DATETIME  = '20190501'

SELECT 
    tbl.PERSON_ID, dsc.STATUS
FROM
    Tab_Civil_Events tbl 
INNER JOIN 
    Tab_Civil_Status_Desc dsc ON tbl.new_Status = dsc.ID 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         PERSON_ID,
         MAX(Ref_Date) AS event_date 
     FROM 
         Tab_Civil_Events
     WHERE 
         Ref_Date <= @QueryDate
     GROUP BY 
         PERSON_ID) t1 ON tbl.PERSON_ID = t1.PERSON_ID 
                       AND t1.event_date = tbl.ref_date
```

- [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d290cf/8/0)

**3rd approach**: temporal tables

I am posting this part after you mentioned that you can change the way the data is stored.

Using SQL Server 2016 or a newer version, you can use temporal tables to simplify querying your data.

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15):

> SQL Server 2016 introduced support for temporal tables (also known as system-versioned temporal tables) as a database feature that brings built-in support for providing information about data stored in the table at any point in time rather than only the data that is correct at the current moment in time.

Temporal tables are implemented as a pair of tables, a current table and a history table. Within each of these tables, start and end dates are stored and used to define the period of validity for each row.

You can refer to the following resources to learn more about this type of data structure:

- [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [First Look at System-Versioned Temporal Tables-Part 1: Creating Tables and Modifying Data](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-1-creating-tables-and-modifying-data)
- [First Look at System-Versioned Temporal Tables-Part 2: Querying Data and Optimization Considerations](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-2-querying-data-and-optimization)
- [Tips Concerning Temporal Tables](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/tips-concerning-temporal-tables)
- [Temporal Tables, Partitioning, and ColumnStore Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/temporal-tables-partitioning-columnstore-indexes/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hadi this is really clear and straightforward; however BenThul and SteveC mentioned the existance of Temporal Tables,  the best practice would be to use the same approach as we used or those temporal tables?

Comment: @m.falconelli In case you can change the data structure, you should go with [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). In case you do not have the permission to alter the data structure you can use T-SQL as I mentioned.

Comment: @m.falconelli temporal table will simplify the SQL queries you need to retrieve the data. Before deciding to go with this approach you can check the [considerations and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-ver15) of those tables and some of the [usage scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-usage-scenarios?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @m.falconelli Also, several good resources can be found online: (1) [Creating Tables and Modifying Data](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-1-creating-tables-and-modifying-data), (2) [Querying Data and Optimization Considerations](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-2-querying-data-and-optimization), (3) [Tips Concerning Temporal Tables](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/tips-concerning-temporal-tables)

Comment: @m.falconelli I edited my answer to include all those information. Good Luck